# Magento sending order confirmation emails twice

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i have an issue with magneto 1.7. New year is come and my customers receiving 2 order confirmation emails: first email with 1 year ago date and second is correct email. Where i can add date checking condition in the code ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?